# Accessing to internal variables of SWF flash file

Tags: flash, browser, actionscript

Is there anyway accessing, action script variables inside an SWF flash file? I can do it for Javascript and browsers like Firefox and Chrome let me to access variable contents from developer mode, however i want to do something like this for an flash file on its runtime.

Answer (score 3):

You can't access variables directly but you can call a function inside an swf that would return some value to Javascript.

Javascript:

```
// you might need to make sure the swf already exists. The id is the id of your swf object in HTML
var mySWF = document.getElementById("mySWF");
var myResult = mySWF.getScore();
```

AS3:

```
if(ExternalInterface.available)
{
    ExternalInterface.addCallback("getScore", onScoreRequested);
}

private function onScoreRequested():String
{ 
    return _myLocalVariableInAS3; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript it's possible since the code is rendered (*processed*) by the browsers themselves anyway, so you can simply change variables during **run-time** and see immediate results (via page refresh, etc).

SWF is compiled code just like an `.exe` or `.apk` or `.dmg`, so you can't just change vars without needing to re-compile.

Could try [**JPEXS Flash Decompiler**](https://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/download/) to adjust code & vars if needed for simple testing/learning.
Savethe code changes before re-compiling (exporting) as new SWF file. Test in browser as usual.